# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException:For input string: on Intellij IDEA

Tags: java

```
int[] a = new int[3];

        String s = e.nextLine();
        String[] sa = s.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0;i<sa.length;i++){
            a[i]=Integer.parseInt(sa[i]);
        }
```

I could not find any issue. Getting this error...

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
> string: ""    at
> java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
> at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)   at
> java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)    at
> Team.main(Team.java:23)

I think my Intellij IDEA is having some trouble. Does this error appear, if IDE does not work well?

Comment: an empty String is not a valid numerical value, that is the whole problem. This has nothing at all to do with your IDE

Comment: That is a String array...."sa" i have printed the array to see its working or not and its working...its printing an array

Comment: yes, but one of the elements is an empty String. And when you try to parse that to a numeric value, that's when you get that error

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I don't think so....the split(" ") ignoring all the empty Strings/spaces...isnt it?

Comment: no. it doesn't ignore it, it adds empty Strings as elements to the result array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your string has two or more blank spaces one after the other so when you do the split(" ") it will return you empty strings between those spaces.

You have to remove the empty strings before trying to convert to integer.
You can do that using an if statement:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0;i<sa.length;i++){
     if(!sa[i].isEmpty()){
            a[j]=Integer.parseInt(sa[i]);
            j++;
     }
}
```

Comment: that approach has it risks, you might be loosing numbers you did provide

Comment: No, because this way you are only filter out the empty strings so none numbers will be lost

Comment: ehm, yes, you do. the length of a is hardcoded to 3, but "4     7  4" split by " ", what does that give? rember, you may think you jump over the non numerical value, but that is a position in the target array that remains empty.

Comment: this example doesn't cause any trouble because sa[i]=["4","7","4"] so it will convert them right. The problem is with something like "4__7_4" with two spaces between 4 and 7 in this cause efectively will cause to throw an IndexOutOfbounds exception. It will be necessary to not use the same index  to iterate over 'sa' and 'a' arrays